# Are there more positive integers than perfect squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Intuitively, there are more positive integers than perfect squares, since every perfect square is already positive, and many other positive integers exist besides. However, the set of positive integers is not in fact larger than the set of perfect squares: both sets are **infinite** and **countable** and can therefore be put in **one-to-one correspondence**. Nevertheless if one goes through the natural numbers, the squares become increasingly scarce.

Although, for every $n^2$ there is a $n$, where, $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ and since that is the case, the number of positive integers and perfect squares should be equal, in that sense. So, I'm wondering which way to approach this problem.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) may interest you. Actually, so may [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_set_(combinatorics)).

Comment: You've already answered your own question if "more" is interpreted as cardinality, so clearly *that* is not the intended interpretation in your title question. However, the body of your post does not say *what* interpretation is intended... making it hard to answer the title question.

Comment: @LeeMosher: By "more" I mean cardinality(the number of positive integers or perfect squares). What's confusing me is the intuitive perspective of the side and the set-theory perspective of the side, I'm not being able to correlate the problem between these two concepts.

Comment: The problem is your intuition is based on your experience with finite sets, where it gets you the right answers. For infinite sets, you have to retrain your intuition – the things that work for finite sets, don't work any more. There is no reason why they should.

Answer (score 1):

You have essentially answered your own question!

From the standard perspective of set theory, these two sets have the same cardinality. That is to say, there are the same number of each. The matching is the one that you specify: Each "perfect square" is of the form $n^2$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, which means you can match $n^2$ and $n$ to establish the bijection between these two sets.

(**Small note:** You write $\mathbb{Z}$ in your question but are asking about positive integers; the common notation for the set of integers that are positive is $\mathbb{Z}^+$.)

If you feel that your question remains unanswered despite this response, then you may need to edit in order to be more precise.

Comment: @Benjamin Dickman: I made the correction. However, I understand that from the set-theory perspective both sets are equal in terms of cardinality(they are the same number of each) due to bijection. But consider the set $[1, n]$, as n gets larger there are more positive integers than perfect squares $\leq{n}$. This observation says the otherwise.

Comment: @user18724 One could define set $A$ as smaller than set $B$ whenever $A \subset B$. For historical reasons – read up on Dedekind, Cantor, etc! – the definition of $A$ and $B$ having the same size in e.g. an intro set theory class is *exactly* that there exists a one-to-one matching between elements of $A$ and $B$. And you have precisely that here! [You may read, with interest, a similar account of why "positive integers" and "positive evens" have the same size, too.

Comment: It is true that for any $n$ there is no one-to-one correspondence between $\{1,2,3,.....n\}$ and $\{1,4,9,......, m^2\}$ (where $m^2 \le n < (m+1)^2$ so $m \le \sqrt n$) but those sets are finite.  If the set of squares were unlimited and infinite it wouldn't be restricted to being less than or equal to the square root of $n$; it could be as large as we like and hit and match all of the $\{1,2,3,...\}$. Infinite vs. finite change intution completely.